# What are articles and why are they only visible on mobile web?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I was browsing Stack Overflow on my phone and went to my profile. Scrolling down under tags, I saw a section called "Articles", which helpfully said "You have not created any articles". Looking on my profile via the browser, this section is not visible in my browser. However, if I go into dev tools and turn on phone emulation and refresh the screen, the section becomes visible.

**What are articles, and why are they only visible in the profile when browsing via a mobile device (or asking your browser to pretend to be a mobile device)?**

Here is a screenshot with a freehand red circle indicating the section in question.

[image: A screenshot of the user activity page with articles section indicated]

This is the "activity" view of my SO profile. For example, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419705/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas). You can observe this strange section on every user's profile (go to "activity" sub-view) on a mobile device or with mobile emulation turned on in your browser.

Comment: Just more SO Teams leaking into areas it doesn't belong.

Comment: Whoops! We'll get this patched up tomorrow! Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed! It looked like we had some leaking going on. This has now been patched so you shouldn't see it on your profile page in the mobile view any longer. I can confirm that I don't see it any more.

Thanks for the report! Glad we were able to get a quick fix out!