# Articles are once again leaking

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, collectives, articles

Following on from [What are articles and why are they only visible on mobile web?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406820/283366), they're back and this time not just for mobile web.

[image: articles]

I'm not [in any collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408754/283366), don't use Teams and cannot see or create any kind of post labelled as an *Article* so why am I seeing this?

Answer (score 9):

The "Articles" section was added to all user profiles since we launched the ability for anyone to [propose a new article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/propose-article). This was posted as an update to the [Community input for article guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413357/community-input-needed-the-guidelines-for-collectives-articles).

To access this feature, you need to be a Member of a collective. Any user with an account can become a Member of a collective by selecting the join button. This means any user has the ability to be the author of an article.

The reason you're seeing "Articles" even though you're not part of a Collective or Team, is because we're matching the same behavior we have for the other sections in the profile. For example, if a user doesn't have any questions, we don't remove the "Questions" page from their profile, same for "Bounties", "Bookmarks", etc.

Comment: It seems like the confusion over this could be addressed by giving some instruction on this page. “Begin contributing by [joining a collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives).” And especially since, unlike questions, answers, bookmarks—and, to a lesser degree, bounties—collectives are easy to miss, and especially if the current (limited set of) collectives don’t overlap with your area of specialization.

Comment: That said, to maintain consistency, I don’t think this type of “get started” text would be unwelcome or inappropriate on _any_ of these pages, for the case where there wasn’t any prior activity.

Comment: I agree that this could be improved @JeremyCaney. At the very least, we can have the word "articles" [link to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/propose-article) that explains how to write/propose articles in greater detail. This matches what most of the other pages are doing currently and it can be done fairly quickly. The 'get started' style of text is a good idea as well but ideally we would want to apply that style to all the pages, as you mentioned, and that's a larger conversation not on our roadmap at this time.